# How does same capacitor with different dielectric affects the circuit?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, decoupling-capacitor, dielectric

I am working on a project and finalizing 0.1uF capacitor with 50VDC(decoupling). I am finding with different dielectrics. My question is how does two diffrenet capacitor having same capacitance and footprint and voltage rating but only diffrent dielectric will affect my overall effect on circuit. Capacitors I was looking are mentioned below
1 [C1206C104M5RAC](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/KEMET/C1206C104M5RAC?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvsSlwiRhF8qoWac7aB9v08YsIlqBUYK%2Fw%3D)
2 [C1206C104Z5VACTU](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/KEMET/C1206C104Z5VACTU?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvsSlwiRhF8qoWac7aB9v08Axi7a17Q%2Fco%3D)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is how does two diffrenet capacitor having same
>   capacitance and footprint and voltage rating but only diffrent
>   dielectric will affect my overall effect on circuit.

On some circuits it will have no affect and on some other circuits it may have a significant effect. Temperature of operation of your circuit can also play a part. On some circuits the better dielectric material of X7R still may not be good enough compared to going to C0G/NP0 dielectric.

So really, to answer this you have to look at your target circuit and ask yourself if the dielectric material is going to cause problems. Look at this picture below for an example of dielectric effects causing capacitor value changes versus temperature: -

[image]

And some dielectrics will modify the terminal capacitance depending on how much DC voltage is applied: -

[image]

Comment: So do I understand correct that the difference between the different dielectrics is that how the capacitance (the reason why we use a capacitor) changes with temperature and applied voltage, or there are other factors as well?

Comment: We choose a capacitor's dielectric to suit the target stability requirements of the circuit.

Comment: Why not just go for Class 1 always?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question that encompasses what you asked in comments and anything else that you think of that is related.